# why lua luaZ_fill read data like this

Tags: c, lua

```
struct Zio {
  size_t n;         /* bytes still unread */
  const char *p;        /* current position in buffer */
  lua_Reader reader;
  void* data;           /* additional data */
  lua_State *L;         /* Lua state (for reader) */
};
int luaZ_fill (ZIO *z) {
  ....
  z->n = size - 1; 
  z->p = buff;
  return char2int(*(z->p++));
}
int luaZ_lookahead (ZIO *z) {
  if (z->n == 0) {
    if (luaZ_fill(z) == EOZ)
      return EOZ;
    else {
      z->n++;  /* luaZ_fill removed first byte; put back it */
      z->p--;
    }
  }
  return char2int(*z->p);
}
```

the function luaZ_fill read data from reader,but why `z->n = size - 1` need -1 ,it seems unuseful.because the functon luaZ_lookahead which called luaZ_fill put back it. why the code do not write like this:

```
int luaZ_fill (ZIO *z) {
  ....
  z->n = size; 
  z->p = buff;
  return char2int(*(z->p));
}
int luaZ_lookahead (ZIO *z) {
  if (z->n == 0) {
    if (luaZ_fill(z) == EOZ)
      return EOZ;
  }
  return char2int(*z->p);
}
```

Comment: try to remove it and read the error output. Usually you'll find it out, why it is needed.

Comment: thank you for your answer, the code confuse me....

Comment: luaZ_fill' is also used by the macro 'zgetc', which needs that
"discount".

-- Roberto

Answer (score 0):

if you have an array and you want to give it a size like:

```
int x = 10;
char arr[x - 1]
```

as all know arr start from 0 to 9 so like The example above if you want to make an array it size is 10 so you have to do like this `arr[x - 1]` unless you will get an array it size is 11 not 10.

Comment: thank you for your answer,i try to discribe it more carefully;please review it again

Comment: Could You give us the struct ZIO

Comment: i put the ZIO above

Comment: luaZ_fill' is also used by the macro 'zgetc', which needs that
"discount".

-- Roberto